# How to bind dynamic row data on dynamic datatable in Primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, binding

I have created a data model in backingbean as shown at the image.

[binded-data-model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIRYd.png)

And I created this ValueExpression:

```
 tabla.setValueExpression("value", context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createValueExpression(context.getELContext(), "#{pc_BackingBean.listaDeTablas[" + String.valueOf(getListaDeTablas().size() - 1) + "]}", List.class));
```

However the row data is not changing when the form is submited.

I already make the string reference for the binding using recursive code (tested).

```
#{pc_BackingBean.listaDeTablas[" + String.valueOf(getListaDeTablas().size() - 1) + "]}"
```

but the next step that binds the row var with the data model does not work.

```
tabla.setVar("criterio");

"#{criterio.puntos}"
```

How can I properly bind the row/column data value with the correct variable in backingbean?

---

Edit:
 The datatable is created in the backingbean.

Comment: So it works in PrimeFaces 5.3 or 6.1?

Comment: The version is 6.1

Comment: Then why do you have 6.0 in the title? Versions do not belong in the title anyway unless it is specifically happening in this and not other versions

Comment: Well, thank you Kukeltje. That was my mistake.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Creating the datatable in a backingbean should very rarely be needed. And considering the sort of questions you have, I think the wrong decision was made for the wrong reasons

Comment: I really think you are right, but then, what is the best way to achieve dynamic tables with dynamic data?

Comment: That question is waaaay to broad...

Comment: Hey, you are a star and saved my day.

Comment: uhhh.... in what way? Your answer below is not what I expected you'd end up with...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue it seems is there a bug on the primefaces datatable method setColumns. When you use it the binding does not work properly.

Instead of use setColumns(columns) use getChildren().addAll(columns);